# Can Flair be abused?

Tags: support, flair, abuse, ban

Is loading other SO users flair pages to create a simple overview of one’s friends scores (rep and badges) considered abuse?

I know how Jeff feels about “social” features and I would be really bummed out if I managed to get myself banned for creating an HTML page with an iframe for each of my buddies. The page would be my browser home page, so it would get quite a few hits during the day. Hardly anything that would put any noticeable load on the servers, but I do wonder if I would get banned on principle alone. :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.

But watch out for the DDOS filter. If you load to many pages too quickly, you get like a 15-20 second ban. This can happen pretty quickly when you are doing 5-10+ page views (flairs are each a view I believe) on a page load.